# Why is the wait() and notify() not working in this program?

Tags: java

I have recently started working on this program, and I'm new to inter-thread communications such as wait and notify. However when I run this, the notify doesn't seem to execute correctly. Here is the code: **(sorry about the extra stuff)**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Main console = new Main();
        console.restart();
    }

    public void restart() throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner restartinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("System has been restarted");
        System.out.println("Restarting requires an admin restart password.");
        System.out.println("You may also login as a normal user to reboot but will cause that account to be temporarily locked.");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for normal user, 2 for admin");
        String input12 = restartinput.nextLine();
        boolean lockall = false;

        if (input12.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Enter username:");
            String input13 = restartinput.nextLine();
            if (input13.equals("normalusertest")) {
                boolean passwordgotten2 = false;
                while (passwordgotten2 == false) {
                    // Not perfect hash function, some Strings and numbers have the same hash.

                    int realhashedpassword2 = 1544190;
                    System.out.println("PIN:");
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String enteredpassword2 = input.nextLine();

                    String plaintextguess2 = new String(enteredpassword2);

                    if (plaintextguess2.hashCode() == realhashedpassword2) {
                        System.out.println("Access granted.");
                        passwordgotten2 = true;
                    } else if (plaintextguess2.equals("/override")) {
                        System.out.println("Admin override password:");
                        String overridepasswordguess2 = input.nextLine();
                        if (overridepasswordguess2.hashCode() == 843331265) {
                            System.out.println("Access granted.");
                            passwordgotten2 = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Access denied.");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Access denied. Incorrect password");
                    }
                }
                for (int w = 0; w <= 45; w++) {
                    System.out.println(".");
                }
                fulllogin(0, 1);

            } else {
                System.out.println("That is not a normal username");
            }

        }

        if (input12.equals("2")) {
            boolean gottenpassword3 = false;
            while (gottenpassword3 == false) {
                System.out.println("Enter the restart password:");
                String input8 = restartinput.nextLine();
                if (input8.hashCode() == 48818447) {
                    System.out.println("Access granted.");
                    System.out.println("Restarting.");
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 45; j++) {
                        System.out.println(".");
                    }
                    gottenpassword3 = true;
                }

            }
            fulllogin(0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void fulllogin(int lockall, int locknormalusertest) throws InterruptedException {
        int lockall1 = lockall;
        int locknormalusertest1 = locknormalusertest;
        Scanner usernameScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Username:");
        String inputtedusername = usernameScanner.nextLine();

        String username = login(inputtedusername, lockall1, locknormalusertest1);
        int currentadministrativelevel = 0;
        if (username.equals("admintest")) {
            currentadministrativelevel = 2;
        }
        if (username.equals("normalusertest")) {
            currentadministrativelevel = 1;
        }
        runCommands(username, currentadministrativelevel, lockall, locknormalusertest);
    }

    public void runCommands(String username, int administrativelevel, int lockall, int locknormalusertest) throws InterruptedException {

        int currentadministrativelevel = administrativelevel;
        System.out.println("Command:");
        Scanner commandinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input2 = commandinput.nextLine();
        if (input2.equals("/manage")) {
            if (currentadministrativelevel == 2) {
                System.out.println("1 user to manage");
                System.out.println("Enter 1 to manage normalusertest");
                if (commandinput.nextLine().equals("1")) {
                    System.out.println("1 to view data, 2 to manage password, 3 to lock/unlock user");
                    String input1 = commandinput.nextLine();
                    if (input1.equals("1")) {
                        System.out.println("No data to view currently");
                    }
                    if (input1.equals("2")) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "To log in to this account use '/override' as the password. The admin override password is the square of the password for this account.");

                    }
                    if (input1.equals("3")) {
                        System.out.println("'/lock' or '/unlock'");
                        System.out.println("Command:");
                        String input10 = commandinput.nextLine();
                        if (input10.equals("/lock")) {
                            System.out.println("Reenter password to confirm lock:");
                            System.out.println("Reenter PIN:");
                            String input9 = commandinput.nextLine();
                            if (input9.hashCode() == 1662305) {
                                System.out.println("Locking normalusertest.");
                                for (int o = 0; o <= 45; o++) {
                                    System.out.println(".");
                                }
                                fulllogin(lockall, 1);
                            }
                        }
                        if (input10.equals("/unlock")) {
                            System.out.println("Reenter password to confirm unlock:");
                            System.out.println("Reenter PIN:");
                            String input11 = commandinput.nextLine();
                            if (input11.hashCode() == 1662305) {
                                System.out.println("Unlocking normalusertest.");
                                for (int p = 0; p <= 45; p++) {
                                    System.out.println(".");
                                }
                                fulllogin(lockall, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            if (currentadministrativelevel == 1) {
                System.out.println("No users to manage.");
            }
        }
        if (input2.equals("/chat")) {
            System.out.println("'/view' or '/send'");
            String input14 = commandinput.nextLine();
            if (input14.equals("/send")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a user to send a message to. Capitalization matters.");
                String input15currenttouser = commandinput.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Message:");
                String input16currentmessage = commandinput.nextLine();
                try {
                    sendMessage(username, input15currenttouser, input16currentmessage, lockall, locknormalusertest);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            if (input14.equals("/view")) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    boolean viewed = true;
                    notifyAll();
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                }
            }

        }

        if (input2.equals("/logout")) {
            System.out.println("Logging out.");
            ;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 45; i++) {
                System.out.println(".");
            }
            fulllogin(lockall, locknormalusertest);
        } else {
            runCommands(username, currentadministrativelevel, lockall, locknormalusertest);
        }

    }

    public String login(String username, int lockall, int locknormalusertest) throws InterruptedException {
        if (username.equals("normalusertest") && (lockall == 1 || locknormalusertest == 1)) {
            System.out.println("This account has been temporarily locked.");
            fulllogin(lockall, locknormalusertest);
        }
        if (username.equals("normalusertest") && lockall == 0 && locknormalusertest == 0) {

            boolean passwordgotten = false;
            while (passwordgotten == false) {
                // Not perfect hash function, some Strings and numbers have the same hash.

                int realhashedpassword = 1544190;
                System.out.println("PIN:");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                String enteredpassword = input.nextLine();

                String plaintextguess = new String(enteredpassword);

                if (plaintextguess.hashCode() == realhashedpassword) {
                    System.out.println("Access granted.");
                    passwordgotten = true;
                } else if (plaintextguess.equals("/override")) {
                    System.out.println("Admin override password:");
                    String overridepasswordguess = input.nextLine();
                    if (overridepasswordguess.hashCode() == 843331265) {
                        System.out.println("Access granted.");
                        passwordgotten = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Access denied.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Access denied. Incorrect password");
                }
            }
            return "normalusertest";
        }
        if (username.equals("admintest")) {
            boolean passwordgotten = false;
            while (passwordgotten == false) {
                // Not perfect hash function, some Strings and numbers have the same hash.
                int realhashedpassword = 1662305;
                System.out.println("PIN:");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                String enteredpassword = input.nextLine();

                String plaintextguess = new String(enteredpassword);

                if (plaintextguess.hashCode() == realhashedpassword) {
                    System.out.println("Access granted.");
                    passwordgotten = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Access denied. Incorrect password");
                }
            }
            return "admintest";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid username");
            return "error";
        }

    }

    public void sendMessage(String fromuser, String touser, String message, int lockall, int locknormalusertest) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            fulllogin(lockall, locknormalusertest);
            boolean viewed = false;
            while (viewed == false) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("notify test");
        }

    }

}
```

After /view is typed, the program just waits and then has "Command:" again, even though it should be printing "notify test".

Comment: It’s a lot of code alright. Is there no possibility that you could boil it down to [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't grasp the whole concept of the application, but two issues seem apparent:

1. You're not starting any threads, therefore, there won't be any
   inter-thread communications, because the only thread you'll have is
   `Main`. Running your application on multiple threads could be
   achieved, for example, by having `Main`  extend `Thread`, creating
   multiple instances in your static `main` method, and calling 
   `start()` on each. (This is just a technical example that most
   likely wouldn't be  appropriate for your needs, as you wouldn't want
   to start printing to the  console from multiple threads.)
2. The following synchronized blocks are trying to communicate via a
   `boolean viewed`, but since they're each creating it as their own
   local variable, they never get to each other:

   ```
   synchronized (this) {
       fulllogin(lockall, locknormalusertest);
       boolean viewed = false;
       while (viewed == false) {
           wait();
       }
       System.out.println("notify test");
   }

   // ...

   synchronized (this) {
       boolean viewed = true;
       notifyAll();
       Thread.sleep(15000);
   }
   ```

   Threads need to communicate via data that's scoped appropriately to be 
   accessible to all of them. For example, if you create the threads as in my 
   example in #1, you can create a static field on `Main` and all 
   instances will have access to that.

   ```
   public class Main {

       // The 'static' keyword makes this variable available to all Main instances
       private static boolean viewed = false;

       // ...
   ```

I'd suggest that you read up on Java scopes and dig into this excellent resource to get a better grasp on the concepts of multithreading: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html

Comment: How would I change it so that the variable isn't local but rather applies to all threads?

Comment: That can't be answered easily, since you don't have threads and I don't know how your code will change in order to introduce them. But for example, if you create them as in my example in #1, you could create a static field on `Main` which all instances would have access to. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: `volatile` does not make sense for a variable accessed inside `synchronized` blocks.  The synchronization does what volatile would normally do.  And of course, synchronization is required anyway, in order to call wait and notify.